# EJB like functionality in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, ejb

I started in Enterprise Java development a few years back and it seems there has been lot of advancements / changes; so I am trying to understand a bit more about the quick history of EJB and the pain points which resulted in development of Spring Framework. Now, as of present, I understand EJB world is easy, that is we don't need to extend or implement any framework specific stuff.

I am having difficult in understand which functionality in Spring framework acts as EJB.

## When we do development in pure EJB, we can have:

JSP / Servlets -> EJB and EJB have business logic, and the services to EJB are provided by the EJB container. This is clear to me (or I assume I have correct understanding).

Now, comes the doubt; which is the "thing" we use to encapsulated the business logic when we use plain Spring framework? I read that we in Spring MVC framework we can use the `@Service` annotation to a bean which acts at service / business layer; but again this is all a single framework "Spring MVC"; EJB can exist of its own, but what is equivalent in Spring? How can write a code in Spring framework which would have the business logic only (the way EJB have).

Can anyone please help me understand this? I did read [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415530/what-is-ejb-alternative-in-spring-framework), but my doubt still remain haunting in mind.

Comment: Spring MVC covers the... web-MVC part of the framework. You can perfectly develop Spring-based transactional business services without using Spring MVC as the presentation layer.

Comment: Spring is intended to replace EJBs.  That was the original reason it was created.   If you use Spring and its POJO model you don't need EJBs.  Business logic will go in services or POJOs of your choosing.  It's not the same as the EJB model.  It's simpler.  If you use Spring Boot, you don't even need a Java EE app server.  You can run on a JRE using an executable JAR.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks for your comment. What I am trying to understand is  how to develop the "business" only component in Spring. Can you please explain a bit more, please.

Comment: You write a class, with public methods, and annotate it (by convention) with `@Service`(and `@Transactional`if you wantit to be transactional). It's not that different from writing an EJB, where you would do the same thing but with a `@Stateless` annotation.

Comment: @duffymo: So there is no direct 1:1 replacement of EJB in Spring? The service annotation is for Spring MVC, assuming if we aren't using Spring MVC, then how can we develop the business logic in Spring framework? This is what my confusion is.

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said you use POJOs, not EJBs.  You put the logic in services, where it belongs.  You can choose to deploy them as SOAP, REST, or just interface based POJOs used by a controller.

Comment: Your mistake is that you think `@Service` is an annotation from Spring MVC. It's not.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes this is what I have been thinking that `@service` can be used in Spring MVC, because it uses the services which the container provides (and typically it is web container). So, for a standalone program who would provide the service which it expects from its run time environment (like transnational services); this is the reason for my doubts.

Comment: If it's a remote service you'll have to tell the Spring controller how to connect to it.  If it's a Spring-injected bean, all you have to do is wire it in.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments, I think my understanding of Spring is still not clear as to how it compares with EJB, can you please suggest me some pointer which I can refer to?

Comment: Transactions are handled by Spring. It has an entire package tree (and a jar file) dedicated to transaction management. Why don't you just read the reference documentation?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my questions, I would go through the reference documentation for clarifications. Thanks you both a ton.